# Индексы mysql

Tags: mysql

Привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда нужно добавлять индексы в таблицу mysql? Один раз при создании таблицы или каждый раз при INSERT'e? А то в интернете куча статей на тему того, для чего они нужны, и как они работают, а вот про добавление ничего не сказано..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что такое индексы и для чего они вполне внятно описано в этой заметке: "[Использование индексов в MySQL (mysq; database index optimization)](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/mysql_index.txt.html)"

Comment: спасибо, в статье написано много того, что другие упускают. Я так понял если я делаю выборки по одному полю, то достаточно один раз добавить соответствующий индекс и всё?

Comment: индексы это свойства таблицы/базы (схема) соответственно добавление индексов, должно быть в рамках создания схемы, т.е. там-же где вы делаете  `CREATE TABLE`, в том смысле, что у вас же не возникает вопрос "должен ли я делать `CREATE TABLE` при каждом `INSERT` ?"

Comment: @eicto, окей, понятно  
Я тут случайно индексов насоздавал, безымянных, теперь не понимаю, как их удалить...

Comment: а, всё нормально, нашёл где названия посмотреть  
SHOW INDEX IN tblname  
И там столбец KEY NAME

Comment: @huffman ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Ну кроме CREATE TABLE есть ещё ALTER TABLE...

В случае @Dazar

      ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP INDEX ...